# Create custom object(candidate) record when user self-register's on community (lightning)

Tags: apex, community, lightning, customer-portal

I am working with communities and was implementing the [recruiting app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_app_arch.htm) using community. i want the candidate to *self register* and when a new candidate self registers, a candidate(custom object record) must be created.

Problem here is, when a new user registers, a new contact related to an account specified is created. i want to create a new candidate instead of a contact.

I am very confused implementing it. How to bypass the existing scenario (i.e. user > contact) and create user > candidate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In salesforce customer communities (I assume that's what you are implementing) youmust have a contact. This is simply because the contact that gets created will be used to create the user. The user links back to the contact and account of that contact. So you will need to keep this.

If you also want to create a 'Candidate' record, you can use Process Builder to create a record when a contact or user is created.

I hope this helps.